# No boot device found

Tags: windows-10, bios, dell-latitude

I have a Dell latitude E5470. Sometimes not always, when I turn on the laptop it shows NO BOOT DEVICE FOUND.
I tried a new hard drive but that does not work.

Comment: Change the SATA cable.

Comment: Do you have any idea if the SATA port is directly soldered to the laptop’s board or routed thru an FFC cable? If FFC cable, just try re-connecting the same. However, to do this, you would mostly require to open the laptop and that might void the warranty. Quick & relatively easy check can be to see if there’s any newer BIOS update for your laptop and try updating to a newer version of BIOS. See if that helps.